# Truncated find ./ command

Tags: linux, unix, find

If I do `find ./`, I get results similar to:

```
/Volumes/FulfilmentArray//.Trashes/1060/ffmpeg2pass-0.log.mbtree.temp
```

Is there a way to do the `find ./` command to return only the filename and container folder? In the above case it would be:

```
1060/ffmpeg2pass-0.log.mbtree.temp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find ./ | rev | cut -d/ -f-2 | rev
```

A little explanation might go a long way. The commands used:

- rev: reverses the order of characters in every line. ([man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?rev))
- cut: remove sections from each line of files. ([man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cut))

So the previous code is doing the following with an example:

1. Prints out a path to all files relative to where the current directory

   ```
   ./Machine Learning - Stanford/Self-notes/08-10.txt
   ```
2. Reverses the path string

   ```
   txt.01-80/seton-fleS/drofnatS - gninraeL enihcaM/.
   ```
3. Cuts the string at the second forward slash leaving the first part (so that includes the file name and containing folder, relative to where the folder in which find was executed in)

   ```
   txt.01-80/seton-fleS --separated here-- /drofnatS - gninraeL enihcaM/.
   ```
4. Reverses the result

   ```
   Self-notes/08-10.txt
   ```

Answer (score 2):

```
find ./ | rev | cut -d/ -f-2 | rev
```

Comment: Thanks. Does this take any longer than the normal find command? I need to run this on a volume with approximately 1M files.

Comment: Leaves leading slash in case of result like `./file`, i.e. file in current dir.

Comment: @David542 About 1-2 seconds longer. Not a factor in comparison to the time find takes. :)

Comment: Since you have a large amount of data this is a lot of pipes. If you are in bash, each pipe is a sub-shell and gets its own copy of the data. This memory isn't freed until all sub-shells are done.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure awk could be swapped out for sed. I added the "-type f" flag since you said filenames, but if you want directories too, just remove it.

```
find ./ -type f|awk -F'/' '{ print $(NF-1)"/"$NF }'
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be one way to go about it:

```
find . | awk -F "/" '{ if (NF > 2) { print $(NF-1) "/" $NF; } else { print $NF; }}'
```